# Get property with oldest date

Tags: javascript

I'm in a situation where I need to store some data in an object, but I can only have a set number of that data due to browser limitations. Since my app also needs to be able to get this data, I am storing it  in an object where the keys of the properties are identifiers.

The data looks like this:

```
memory = {
    13: {
        last_updated: 241,
        ...
    },
    26: {
        last_updated: 363,
        ....
    }
}
```

`last_updated` would be a `Date.now()` string of course. This object can not have more than 6 properties. When it reaches that length, I need to start replacing the oldest properties with new data. How do I get the oldest property of the object?

Comment: Have you tried looking at each object and finding the one with the oldest `last_updated` value? FYI, `Date.now()` returns a number, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to just sort the objects keys by the last updated timestamp, and pop of the last one, the oldest one

```
var oldest = memory[Object.keys(memory).sort(function(a,b) {
    return memory[b].last_updated - memory[a].last_updated
}).pop()];
```

Answer (score 0):

This would take the newest 6 items from the `memory` object.

```
var freshMemory = Object.keys(memory)
  .map(function (k) { return [k, data[k]] })
  .sort(function (a, b) { return b[1].last_updated - a[1].last_updated; })
  .slice(0, 6)
  .reduce(function (o, v) { o[v[0]] = v[1]; return o; }, {});
```

A short explanation

1. The `Object.keys` combined with the `.map` method will transfer the object to an array containing two-tuples (the key and the value)
2. then the `.sort` will sort the array by `last_updated` in reverse order
3. then the `.slice` will take the first 6 items
4. and finally `.reduce` will convert the array with two-tuples back to an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0;i < 5; i++){
  obj[i] = {date:Date.now() + i};
}

function addNew(date){
  if(obj.length < 5){
      obj[obj.length] = {date:date};
      return;
  }
  var arr = [];
  for(var prop in obj){
      arr.push({prop:prop,date:obj[prop].date})  
  }
  var last = arr.sort(function(a, b){return b.date-a.date})[0].prop;
  obj[last].date = date;
}
addNew(Date.now() + 100);
console.log(obj);
```

You need to add new properties to the object only by using the `addNew(...)` function in order for this to work.